# why am I getting error "JSX element 'div' has no corresponding closing tag" in my code

Tags: html, reactjs, e-commerce

I am working on e-commerse website as a coding project by following a tutorial on youtube. I copied my HTML code to App.js in React.js. I still dont understand the error messages.

```html
<main className="main">
  <div className="content">
    <ul className="products">
      <li>
        <div className="product">
          <img className="product-image" src="./Images/Club-Beer.png" alt="product">
          <div className="product-name">
            <a href="product.html"> Club Beer</a>
          </div>
          <div className="product-brand">Accra Brewery Limited</div>
          <div className="product-price">Ghc 8</div>
          <div className="product-rating">4.8 Stars (10 Reviews)</div>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div className="product">
          <img className="product-image" src="./Images/2.-Club-Shandy.png" alt="product">
          <div className="product-name">
            <a href="product.html">Club-Shandy</a>
          </div>
          <div className="product-brand">Accra Brewery Limited</div>
          <div className="product-price">Ghc 6</div>
          <div className="product-rating">4.6 Stars (12 Reviews)</div>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        div className="product">
        <img className="product-image" src="./Images/6.-Beta-Malt.png" alt="product">
        <div className="product-name">
          <a href="product.html"> Beta-Malt</a>
        </div>
        <div className="product-brand">Accra Brewery Limited</div>
        <div className="product-price">Ghc 3</div>
        <div className="product-rating">4.4 Stars (10 Reviews)</div>

  </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div className="product">
      <img className="product-image" src="./Images/Eagle-Extra-Stout.png" alt="product">
      <div className="product-name">
        a href="product.html">Extra Stout </a>
      </div>
      <div className="product-brand">Accra Brewery Limited</div>
      <div className="product-price">Ghc 6</div>
      <div className="product-rating">4.8 Stars (14 Reviews)</div>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div className="product">
      <img className="product-image" src="./Images/Stella-Artois-Upload.png" alt="product">
      <div className="product-name">
        <a href="product.html"> Stella Artois</a>
      </div>
      <div className="product-brand">Accra Brewery Limited</div>
      <div className="product-price">Ghc 6</div>
      <div className="product-rating">4.8 Stars (40 Reviews)</div>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div className="product">
      <img className="product-image" src="./Images/Guiness.jpg" alt="product">
      <div className="product-name">
        <a href="product.html"> Guiness</a>
      </div>
      <div className="product-brand">Guiness</div>
      <div className="product-price">Ghc 6</div>
      <div className="product-rating">4.8 Stars (60 Reviews)</div>

    </div>
  </li>

  </ul>
  </div>

</main>
<footer className="footer">
  All right reserved.
</footer>
</div>


); } export default App;
```

Some Error messages

```
{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/User/Desktop/E-Commence/frontend/src/App.js",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "17008",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "JSX element 'div' has no corresponding closing tag.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 7,
    "startColumn": 6,
    "endLineNumber": 7,
    "endColumn": 9
}
```

Comment: Just prettyprinting your HTML shows the errors `<li>
        div className="product">`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing all sorts of opening/closing tags here's a working and formatted html for your code.
You're missing all sorts of opening/closing tags here's a working and formatted
html for your code.

```
<div>
  <main className="main">
    <div className="content">
      <ul className="products">
        <li>
          <div className="product">
            <img
              className="product-image"
              src="./Images/Club-Beer.png"
              alt="product"
            />
            <div className="product-name">
              <a href="product.html"> Club Beer</a>
            </div>
            <div className="product-brand">Accra Brewery Limited</div>
            <div className="product-price">Ghc 8</div>
            <div className="product-rating">4.8 Stars (10 Reviews)</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div className="product">
            <img
              className="product-image"
              src="./Images/2.-Club-Shandy.png"
              alt="product"
            />
            <div className="product-name">
              <a href="product.html">Club-Shandy</a>
            </div>
            <div className="product-brand">Accra Brewery Limited</div>
            <div className="product-price">Ghc 6</div>
            <div className="product-rating">4.6 Stars (12 Reviews)</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div className="product">
            <img
              className="product-image"
              src="./Images/6.-Beta-Malt.png"
              alt="product"
            />
            <div className="product-name">
              <a href="product.html"> Beta-Malt</a>
            </div>
            <div className="product-brand">Accra Brewery Limited</div>
            <div className="product-price">Ghc 3</div>
            <div className="product-rating">4.4 Stars (10 Reviews)</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div className="product">
            <img
              className="product-image"
              src="./Images/Eagle-Extra-Stout.png"
              alt="product"
            />
            <div className="product-name">
              <a href="product.html">Extra Stout </a>
            </div>
            <div className="product-brand">Accra Brewery Limited</div>
            <div className="product-price">Ghc 6</div>
            <div className="product-rating">4.8 Stars (14 Reviews)</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div className="product">
            <img
              className="product-image"
              src="./Images/Stella-Artois-Upload.png"
              alt="product"
            />
            <div className="product-name">
              <a href="product.html"> Stella Artois</a>
            </div>
            <div className="product-brand">Accra Brewery Limited</div>
            <div className="product-price">Ghc 6</div>
            <div className="product-rating">4.8 Stars (40 Reviews)</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div className="product">
            <img
              className="product-image"
              src="./Images/Guiness.jpg"
              alt="product"
            />
            <div className="product-name">
              <a href="product.html"> Guiness</a>
            </div>
            <div className="product-brand">Guiness</div>
            <div className="product-price">Ghc 6</div>
            <div className="product-rating">4.8 Stars (60 Reviews)</div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer className="footer">All right reserved.</footer>
</div>
```